# Is $f(x)=x$ analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, taylor-expansion, analytic-functions, cauchy-riemann-equations

The real function $f(x)=x$ has no imaginary part. In particular, it does not satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann conditions (the necessary and sufficient condition for a function to be analytic). So from this point of view $f(x)=x$ is non-analytic.

But $f(x)=x$ is *smooth* i.e., infinitely differentiable and admits a Taylor expansion about $x=0$. Isn't this another definition of an analytic function?

Comment: The Cauchy-Riemann equations are equivalent to (complex) differentiability. Analyticity is actually a consequence of complex differentiability, but the Cauchy-Riemann equations don’t define analyticity, particularly in the real case. Anyway, the function $f:z\mapsto\mathrm{Re}(z)$ doesn’t satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations, hence is not complex differentiable, and hence not analytic. However, $f:z\mapsto z$ is, and this is an analytic complex analogue of the given mapping (in fact the only one!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a real analytic function since it has  a power series expansion around each point. Ref. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function

Comment: So one should distinguish between a _real analytic_ function and a _complex analytic_ function?

Comment: Complex analytic functions are differentiable functions defined on open  subsets of $\mathbb C$ and they satisfy C-R equations. @SRS